# WSO2 DSS - INCOMPATIBLE PARAMETERS ERROR Nested Exception

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am getting the error

> INCOMPATIBLE PARAMETERS ERROR Nested Exception : avax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'CallQuery.extractParams', cannot find parameter with type:query-param name:p_orderdetailcode"

for the below structure

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <dat:hdhs_testdetail>
         <dat:p_ordercode>1</dat:p_ordercode>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
          <dat:p_orderdetailcodes>
         <dat:p_orderdetailcode>11</dat:p_orderdetailcode>
         <dat:p_orderdetailcode>12</dat:p_orderdetailcode>
          </dat:p_orderdetailcodes>
      </dat:hdhs_testdetail>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But it is working fine without nested "**p_orderdetailcodes**" like below

```html
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <dat:hdhs_testdetail>
         <dat:p_ordercode>1</dat:p_ordercode>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <dat:p_orderdetailcode>11</dat:p_orderdetailcode>
         <dat:p_orderdetailcode>12</dat:p_orderdetailcode>
      </dat:hdhs_testdetail>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Could you add the definition of your DataService? Is there a reason why you expected the p_orderdetailcodes element?

Comment: <xs:element name="hdhs_testdetail">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="p_ordercode" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="p_orderdetailcode" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>

Comment: It is the common element for other services to use...

Comment: What is the problem here? If it works why can you not use the format of the second payload that you posted?

Comment: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <dat:hdhs_testdetail>
         <dat:p_ordercode>1</dat:p_ordercode>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
          <dat:p_orderdetailcodes>
         <dat:p_orderdetailcode>11</dat:p_orderdetailcode>
         <dat:p_orderdetailcode>12</dat:p_orderdetailcode>
          </dat:p_orderdetailcodes>
      </dat:hdhs_testdetail>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Comment: How to create the above mentioned structure in WSO2 DSS